# how to include separately added system.configuration dll in nuget package

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec, nugetgallery

I'm creating nuget package of my `demo.csproj` I have added `system.configuration` separatly into this project,

> I know that I can add this `system.configuration.dll` into my nuget by
>   using either of adding `<dependencies>` tag or y `<file>` tag inside
>   `.nuspec` file ,
>   but is there any other way around like `copy local=true` for this  instead using `<dependencies>` or '' tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reference standard .NET Framework assemblies, add the following to your *.nuspec* file:

```xml
<frameworkAssemblies>
  <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Configuration" />
</frameworkAssemblies>
```

https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference